# Struggling with regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to find the regular expression I can use to classify data that matches a certain pattern:

Here's a few examples:

```
pli:06e9b616-5712-d0e9-1bc2-000012e61393
pli:6fdd187d-cbdc-3028-4a8d-000020f3449a
pli:0472def9-ccf3-e4e9-ca05-00005fecf9f8
```

As you can see each string begins with pli: and they all have the same pattern even though the  characters are different. Each set of characters is separated by a '-' at the same position.

Comment: So, starts with `pli:`, followed by number/letter/dash one or more times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it in as short an expression as I could think of:

```
pli:(?i)[\da-f]{8}-([\da-f]{4}-){3}[\da-f]{12}
```

The `(?i)` means "ignore case" (saves having to type `a-zA-Z` everywhere), and I've abbreviated the regex by recognising 3 groups of 4 digits in the middle

See a [live demo on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/X2psvlQmk6)

Comment: Thanks, but that came up as invalid. Are there brackets missing here?

Comment: @Amara Yeah. I had a couple of brackets misplaced. It works now and I've edited the answer. See the link to the demo there. btw, this is quite a bit shorter (and therefore nicer) than the other answer :)

Comment: Your both brilliant... Thanks

Comment: Learning regex is a great idea, because it is useable in most languages. If you want to learn, read [this tutorial](http://regular-expressions.mobi/tutorial.html) (btw, that site is the best regex reference on the web), and try to answer some regex questions here - practice makes perfect! :)

Comment: LOL @ Bohemian, not sure I'd be good enough to give anyone else advice, but perhaps with time.  Thanks for the link and the help.  You're a star!!!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it has the form pli:UUID where UUID is a *universally unique identifier*. Try this one:

```
pli:[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}
```

Where I've allowed upper case letters too.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: Excellent! That looks like the one! I've never properly understood this regular expression stuff... Thank you so much